# Running flann with Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, flann

I built flann using cmake and then I ran my program and had the following errors:

> ```
>  **** Build of configuration Debug for project test1 ****
> ```
>
> make all  Building file: ../src/test1.cpp Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
>   g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/test1.d"
>   -MT"src/test1.d" -o"src/test1.o" "../src/test1.cpp" In file included from ../src/test1.cpp:3: /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:45: error:
>   expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before
>   ‘get_hdf5_type’ /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:51: error: expected
>   constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘get_hdf5_type’
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:53: error: expected constructor,
>   destructor, or type conversion before ‘get_hdf5_type’
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:55: error: expected constructor,
>   destructor, or type conversion before ‘get_hdf5_type’
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:57: error: expected constructor,
>   destructor, or type conversion before ‘get_hdf5_type’
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:59: error: expected constructor,
>   destructor, or type conversion before ‘get_hdf5_type’
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:61: error: expected constructor,
>   destructor, or type conversion before ‘get_hdf5_type’
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:63: error: expected constructor,
>   destructor, or type conversion before ‘get_hdf5_type’
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:65: error: expected constructor,
>   destructor, or type conversion before ‘get_hdf5_type’
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:67: error: expected constructor,
>   destructor, or type conversion before ‘get_hdf5_type’
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:69: error: expected constructor,
>   destructor, or type conversion before ‘get_hdf5_type’
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:71: error: expected constructor,
>   destructor, or type conversion before ‘get_hdf5_type’
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h: In function ‘void
>   flann::save_to_file(const flann::Matrix&, const std::string&, const
>   std::string&)’: /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:84: error: there
>   are no arguments to ‘H5Eset_auto’ that depend on a template parameter,
>   so a declaration of ‘H5Eset_auto’ must be available
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:84: note: (if you use
>   ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an
>   undeclared name is deprecated) /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:87:
>   error: ‘herr_t’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:87: error: expected ‘;’ before
>   ‘status’ /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:88: error: ‘hid_t’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:88: error:
>   expected ‘;’ before ‘file_id’ /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:89:
>   error: ‘file_id’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:89: error: ‘H5F_ACC_RDWR’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:89: error:
>   ‘H5P_DEFAULT’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:89: error: there are no arguments
>   to ‘H5Fopen’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of
>   ‘H5Fopen’ must be available /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:91:
>   error: ‘H5F_ACC_EXCL’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:91: error: there are no arguments
>   to ‘H5Fcreate’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration
>   of ‘H5Fcreate’ must be available
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:95: error: ‘hsize_t’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:95: error:
>   expected ‘;’ before ‘dimsf’ /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:96:
>   error: ‘dimsf’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:99: error: expected ‘;’ before
>   ‘space_id’ /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:100: error: expected ‘;’
>   before ‘memspace_id’ /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:102: error:
>   expected ‘;’ before ‘dataset_id’
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:106: error: ‘dataset_id’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:106: error:
>   ‘get_hdf5_type’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:106: error: expected
>   primary-expression before ‘>’ token
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:106: error: expected
>   primary-expression before ‘)’ token
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:106: error: ‘space_id’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:106: error:
>   there are no arguments to ‘H5Dcreate’ that depend on a template
>   parameter, so a declaration of ‘H5Dcreate’ must be available
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:113: error: there are no arguments
>   to ‘H5Dopen’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of
>   ‘H5Dopen’ must be available /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:118:
>   error: ‘status’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:118: error: expected
>   primary-expression before ‘>’ token
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:118: error: expected
>   primary-expression before ‘)’ token
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:118: error: ‘memspace_id’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:121: error:
>   there are no arguments to ‘H5Sclose’ that depend on a template
>   parameter, so a declaration of ‘H5Sclose’ must be available
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:122: error: there are no arguments
>   to ‘H5Sclose’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of
>   ‘H5Sclose’ must be available /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:123:
>   error: there are no arguments to ‘H5Dclose’ that depend on a template
>   parameter, so a declaration of ‘H5Dclose’ must be available
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:124: error: there are no arguments
>   to ‘H5Fclose’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of
>   ‘H5Fclose’ must be available /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h: In
>   function ‘void flann::load_from_file(flann::Matrix&, const
>   std::string&, const std::string&)’:
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:132: error: ‘herr_t’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:132: error:
>   expected ‘;’ before ‘status’ /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:133:
>   error: ‘hid_t’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:133: error: expected ‘;’ before
>   ‘file_id’ /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:134: error: ‘file_id’ was
>   not declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:136:
>   error: expected ‘;’ before ‘dataset_id’
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:140: error: ‘dataset_id’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:140: error:
>   ‘file_id’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:140: error: there are no arguments
>   to ‘H5Dopen’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of
>   ‘H5Dopen’ must be available /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:144:
>   error: expected ‘;’ before ‘space_id’
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:146: error: ‘hsize_t’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:146: error:
>   expected ‘;’ before ‘dims_out’ /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:147:
>   error: ‘space_id’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:147: error: ‘dims_out’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:147: error:
>   there are no arguments to ‘H5Sget_simple_extent_dims’ that depend on a
>   template parameter, so a declaration of ‘H5Sget_simple_extent_dims’
>   must be available /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:151: error:
>   ‘status’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:151: error: ‘get_hdf5_type’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:151: error:
>   expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:151: error: expected
>   primary-expression before ‘)’ token
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:151: error: ‘H5S_ALL’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:151: error:
>   ‘H5P_DEFAULT’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:154: error: there are no arguments
>   to ‘H5Sclose’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of
>   ‘H5Sclose’ must be available /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:155:
>   error: there are no arguments to ‘H5Dclose’ that depend on a template
>   parameter, so a declaration of ‘H5Dclose’ must be available
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:156: error: there are no arguments
>   to ‘H5Fclose’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of
>   ‘H5Fclose’ must be available /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h: In
>   function ‘void flann::load_from_file(flann::Matrix&, const
>   std::string&, const std::string&) [with T = float]’:
>   ../src/test1.cpp:15:   instantiated from here
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:140: error: ‘H5Dopen’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:147: error:
>   ‘H5Sget_simple_extent_dims’ was not declared in this scope
>   ../src/test1.cpp:15:   instantiated from here
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:151: error: ‘H5Dread’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:147: error:
>   ‘H5Sclose’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:140: error: ‘H5Dclose’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:140: error:
>   ‘H5Fclose’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h: In function ‘void
>   flann::save_to_file(const flann::Matrix&, const std::string&, const
>   std::string&) [with T = int]’: ../src/test1.cpp:28:   instantiated
>   from here /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:84: error: ‘H5Eset_auto’
>   was not declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:89:
>   error: ‘H5Fopen’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:89: error: ‘H5Fcreate’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:89: error:
>   ‘H5Dcreate’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:89: error: ‘H5Dopen’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:89: error:
>   ‘H5Dwrite’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:118: error: ‘H5Sclose’ was not
>   declared in this scope /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:106: error:
>   ‘H5Dclose’ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/flann/io/hdf5.h:89: error: ‘H5Fclose’ was not
>   declared in this scope make: *** [src/test1.o] Error 1